# Limitation of IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP on a Windows 2008 Server

Tags: network-programming, windows-server-2008-r2, multicast, ipv4

I want to build an application which wants to recive data from several multicast groups (up to 1.000!) Is this possible with the setsockopt function (IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP)? Or is there a system limit?

Is there another way to do it? Or do I have to use more than one socket?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you'll have to try it. There is bound to he a limit, and 1000 is rather a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found something on this [Microsoft site: INFO: Header and Library Requirement When Set/Get Socket Options at the IPPROTO_IP Level](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257460/en)

There exists a define

`#define IP_MAX_MEMBERSHIPS         20   /* per socket; must fit in one mbuf */`

The mbuf struct has a maximum size of 108 bytes.

[TCP/IP Illustrated: Vol. 2: The Implementation](http://books.google.de/books?id=ESM3CWY5xRYC&pg=PA267&lpg=PA267&dq=ip%20mbuf%20header&source=bl#v=onepage&q=ip%20mbuf%20header&f=false)

Comment: Another explanation I found here: [TCP/IP Illustrated](http://books.google.de/books?id=6H9AxyFd0v0C&pg=PA1076&lpg=PA1076&dq=IP_MAX_MEMBERSHIPS%20header&source=bl#v=onepage&q=IP_MAX_MEMBERSHIPS%20header&f=false)